# Using Spring, Error while retrieving the list of applied migration from metadata table "PUBLIC". "schema_version"

Tags: spring, flyway, data-migration

Console log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "PUBLIC"."schema_version"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.boot.App.main(App.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "PUBLIC"."schema_version"
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.findAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:248) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.allAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:182) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:97) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:136) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:131) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:131) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1102) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:62) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1012) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "version_rank" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT "version_rank","installed_rank","version","description","type","script","checksum","installed_on","installed_by","execution_time","success" FROM "PUBLIC"."schema_version" ORDER BY "version_rank" [42122-190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:835) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:246) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:460) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:402) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:317) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.findAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:225) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2018-05-19 23:43:14.360  INFO 28207 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/home/hugo/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/das-boot/target/classes/, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.4/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.4/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.7/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.30/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-juli-8.0.30.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.2.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar, file:/home/hugo/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/3.2.1/flyway-core-3.2.1.jar]
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <name>das-boot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have searched for how to solve this problem, and it seems like it is because of 'PUBLIC' and 'public' upper and lower case. 
However, I am using Spring so I did not write the init script. How would I go about changing it if that's the case?

ps I already set up the db/migration folder and have a simple create table SQL script in there.